# Witch and Youtube Fullscreen Windows

Tags: fullscreen, youtube, application-switcher

I just installed [Witch](https://manytricks.com/witch/) for one reason only which is that if I make a youtube video fullscreen in Chrome then <kbd>⌘tab</kbd> to another app, when I <kbd>⌘tab</kbd> again to get back to the youtube video OSX instead just switches to the browser in the current space.

Unfortunately when I tried Witch it lets me switch back to the youtube video but the `youtube.com is now full screen` prompt appears **AND NEVER DISAPPEARS**.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out Chrome is apparently creating some special window called "Window". Witch sees that as the previous window and <kbd>⌘tab</kbd> switched to it, not the actual video window. This takes me to the correct space for the video but it's the wrong window.

The solution is to tell Witch to ignore windows with the name "Window" by adding `,Window` the the "Ignore windows with titles:" Behavior settings.

[image: add ,Window]